# ASP.NET - URL Redirection Issue

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have developed a site using ASP.NET 3.5, located within a virtual directory that is on a server running on IIS v5.1.  Just this afternoon as I was fixing something on the development site, I started getting a 404 error ("The resource cannot be found") after clicking on one of the links within an ASP.NET Menu control.  I know why I'm getting the 404, and that's because I keep getting redirected to a Default.aspx page in the directory directly above the virtual directory.  But I don't understand why this would be happening if the URL is pointing to a valid page.

I have checked and double-checked the URL to make sure that I didn't misspell anything (I'm using the relative path, so the URL is something like "~/pgName.aspx").  I've tried creating a new ASPX page and copying/pasting the contents of the other page, but I get the same 404 error.  In addition, I cannot get Intellisense to work after pasting the code (the controls don't show up in the drop down, either).

Comment: I don't have any code for that - I'm trying to figure out why the redirect is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem - there was a session variable that wasn't being set correctly.